# What is a good strategy for Reave?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I cannot find any good uses for Reave. From what I understand, it absorbs a little health and weakens them (and while they are weakened, I get a little bit of extra defense).

But it does not work on many things it seems, like Geth Prime. Normally when it hits, it gives me a glowing aura that represents my extra defense. But when I use it on say Geth Prime, nothing happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very good for spamming biotic detonations with another biotic, for several reasons:

1. It has no travel time, so enemies can't dodge it.
2. It can affect multiple targets, setting up multiple detonation opportunities.
3. It works as both "set up" and "trigger", unlike e.g. Pull which can only initiate a combo, or Throw which can only work as the "trigger".

It's also good on its own against organic targets, but less useful against synthetics, since you only get the extra defense when it's used against organics.

Comment: just be aware people will hate you for using it because of the annoying sound effect :P

Answer (score 5):

As a Drell Adept, it is devastating when you use it to set up explosions triggered by Cluster Grenade.

Cast Reave first, then bounce Cluster Grenades on the floor in between you and a target. This will take out a Brute in one shot on Bronze, and, if executed correctly, will take a third to half off of a Prime/Banshee/Atlas on Gold.

As a Justicar, you can cast your Bubble in a choke point, and take the Warp upgrade. Then cast Reave on anything that walks through the Bubble, setting off explosions.

Plus everything that Hammar said too.

Comment: I don't have Grenades, only Pull. :/

Comment: @Zeno - promote or respec, you're seriously missing out. Plus Pull is ineffective against the more difficult enemies anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fantastic ability when used for setting up/setting off biotic explosions.

Let's take a Drell Adept in multiplayer for example:

Lesser enemies with no shields or shields down: Use Pull to render them helpless, them Reave to detonate.

Larger enemies/bosses: use Reave on them, them throw some cluster grenades to detonate.

Biotic detonations are extremely powerful and unlike some abilities like pull where it works only on unshielded targets, you can throw a Reave on anything, including shields, barriers and armour.

Lots of abilities detonates Reave: warp, throw, cluster grenades, shockwave, biotic sphere, charge and lift & slam in single player.

In multiplayer, if you see other biotics, you can help the team by basically spamming Reave on everything. Assuming your team mates knows what to do, they should be detonating  after your reave. Makes short work of everything.

My reply is only specific to Reave, but there are lots of other combos that you can pull off.

Relix28 created a very comprehensive list of all possible combos here: http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/9629730

Just came out from a gold game with someone spamming reave and another spamming overload.  I was an Asari adept and spammed throw, an ability that sets off both biotic detonations with reave and tech bursts with overload. Absolute fun, fireworks and destruction. =)